# Get parent class name from custom UI elements in iOS

Tags: ios, class, uielement

I have some custom `UIElements` like `UILabel` , `UITextFields` etc in my iOS App . Now i want to get the original element name from which they are derived from on each touch event . How to get the parent class name from the custom `UIElements` ?

Comment: How about `[myElement superclass]`... (or `isKindOfClass:` passing the super class that you want to test against)

Comment: are u subclassed the UI elements ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSObject` `superclass` method to get the superclass.

But in your case you don't want to care about how many inheritances there are.

So the best is to use `isKindOfClass`.

```
if ([element isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
{
    //Do your stuff here
}
```

In order to complete your exact question, to retrieve the parent class name:

`NSString *parentClassName = NSStringFromClass(element.superclass);`

Answer (score 0):

Use NSObject's method `superclass`:

```
Class your_superclass = self.superclass;
```

[Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/superclass)

> Returns the class object for the receiver’s superclass.